# Pass in argument to RACCommand

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa, frp

So I am using RACCommand on a UIButton.  Upon hitting this button, user registration commences.  It looks like:

```
self->_termsOfServicesAcceptButton.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    UserModel* newUser = [[UserModel alloc] initWithUsername:self->_userNameTextField.text password:self->_passwordTextField.text email:self->_emailTextField.text firstname:self->_firstNameTextField.text lastname:self->_lastNameTextField.text];
    return [self termsOfServicesAcceptedSignal:newUser];
}
```

And a status indicator hooks onto the `executing` signal like:

```
[[self->_termsOfServicesAcceptButton.rac_command.executing deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] subscribeNext:^(NSNumber* isSigningUp) {
    @strongify(self);
    if ([isSigningUp boolValue]) {
         [self->_signUpActivityIndicator startAnimating];
         NSLog(@" activity indicator started animating");
    }
    else {
        [self->_signUpActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
        NSLog(@" activity indicator stopped animating");
    }
}];
```

`termsOfServicesAcceptedSignal` is just a wrapper of an existing function like this:

```
RACSignal* signal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    [self termsOfServicesAcceptButtonPressed:newUser withCompletion:^{
        [subscriber sendNext:@(YES)];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
    }];
    return nil;
}];
return signal;
```

Ok, so this works fine.  Now, I want to use results of `newUserModelSignal` from earlier to pass in UserModel info instead of reading it from `textField.text`.  I tried:

```
self->_termsOfServicesAcceptButton.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    return [newUserModelSignal flattenMap:^RACStream *(UserModel* newUser) {
        return [self termsOfServicesAcceptedSignal:newUser];
    }];
}];
```

Which works in that sense that `newUser` is passed in properly, registration succeeds, but the status indicator never stops spinning, i.e. it never receives any message that it ended.

I gather that it's because with the replacement code, RACCommand is no longer automatically subscribing to the `termsOfServicesAcceptedSignal` but rather the `newUserModelSignal`.  So how would I fix this so that the status indicator picks up the `executing` signal correctly?  Thanks.

Comment: How is `newUserModelSignal` implemented? Does it ever complete?